# Can't run Angular application with ng serve

Tags: node.js, angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq866.png)

Hi. 
I can't build and run my Angular application. I tried to reinstall angular/cli, node.js and remove all node modules packages globally but it did not help.

Comment: It seems that jquery is not installed. (You should not have to use jquery within an angular project). 
Also your local version of angular cli is lower that your global. Try run npm i -g angular/cli@latest then Try run npm i angular/cli@latest and npm i jquery

Comment: Providing what error you are getting would help people understand more about your problem.

Comment: try `npm i jquery --save` and run, @HMarteau already give explanation.

Comment: Please include the text of the error as actual text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

try to do:

```
npm install
```

if the error persist you can do

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error still happens after `npm install`, try deleting the whole `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again.